# Remove two results of two different tables with a common field

Tags: mysql, sql, join

Following the first table (first_table):

```
id 
data
status
```

Following the second table (second_table):

```
id
status
final_result
```

I would like to remove all of the results from the second table where `final_result` is equal to 3, and in the first table where `status` is equal to the `status` of results previously deleted. Following my query:

```
DELETE FROM second_table WHERE final_result = '3'
```

I do not know how to continue, can you help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
DELETE FT, ST
FROM first_table AS FT
JOIN second_table AS ST
ON FT.status = ST.status 
AND ST.final_result = '3'
```

Comment: I think you need to sync up your aliases.

Answer (score 1):

you have to delete first the rows of your first table.

```
DELETE FROM first_table where status in (select distinct status from second_table where final_result='3')
DELETE FROM second_table WHERE final_result = '3'
```